# Restricting Generics to a subclass of the current class

Tags: c#

I have two similar classes, so I made a parent class, and 2 classes which derive from it. The thing is that they are both trees of only their own type. So for now I have a parent class which holds a reference list of `public IList<ParentTreeClass> Children { get; set; }`. How can I change the `ParentTreeClass` to force it to be derived from `ParentTreeClass` not including it.

To give a bit more specific example, lets call the classes `ParentTreeClass`, `ImportTree` and `ExportTree`.

```
public class ParentTreeClass {
    public ParentTreeClass Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<ParentTreeClass> Children { get; set; }
    // Other stuff.
}

public class ImportTree : ParentTreeClass {
    // Some overrides.
}

public class ExportTree : ParentTreeClass {
    // Some other overrides.
}
```

As said, once I have a `ExportTree` object, its children and parent should also be `ExportTree` and no other object.

I have thought about Generics like so:

```
public class ParentTreeClass<T> {
    public T Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<T> Children { get; set; }
    // Other stuff.
}
```

But this is not restrictive enought, since I want `T` to be a child of `ParentTreeClass`. I tried adding `where T : ParentTreeClass`. This does not work, cause it tells me to use `where T : ParentTreeClass<T>`, then I run into issues understanding the second `T`.

Can I force a tree to be instances of the same type which derives from `ParentTreeClass`?

Comment: You might want to read Eric Lippert's [Curiouser and curiouser](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser/) for an explanation of the `where T : ParentTreeClass<T>`, and also where some of the failings/drawbacks of this approach are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple to do.

```
public class ParentTreeClass<T> where T : ParentTreeClass<T> {
    public T Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<T> Children { get; set; }
    // Other stuff.
}

public class ImportTree : ParentTreeClass<ImportTree> {
    // Some overrides.
}

public class ExportTree : ParentTreeClass<ExportTree> {
    // Some other overrides.
}
```

This has the drawback that you can go on to define a class like this:

```
public class ImportTree2 : ParentTreeClass<ExportTree> {
    // Some overrides.
}
```

But, so long as you're careful with your definitions this works fine.

Comment: Yes, it guards against accident rather than malicious intent.

Comment: In that case, where it only protects me from accidents, I may as well use no restriction but only T (no where ...). And maybe leave a comment, since it will be easier to understand in 2-3 years by whoever will read this code. But thanks.

Comment: @RamziKahil - This does create the strongly typed trees that you want and the recursive nature of the definition isn't overly difficult to understand in two years if you can get your head around it now.

Comment: Well, it is in no way guaranteed that I will be the guy working on it in a few years, or whenever changes will be required. But thanks for the input. Just in case you're interested, read the first comment on the question. (As smart people said: Just because you can, it doesn't mean that you should) :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this:

```
public class ParentTreeClass<T> where T: ITree
{
    public T Parent { get; set; }
    public IList<T> Children { get; set; }
    // Other stuff.
}

public interface ITree
{
    IList<ITree> Children { get; set; }
    ITree Parent { get; set; }
}

public class ImportTree : ParentTreeClass<ITree>, ITree
{
    // Some overrides.
}

public class ExportTree : ParentTreeClass<ITree>, ITree
{
    // Some other overrides.
}
```

Restriction is not subclass of parent but it restricts T by ITree implementations only

Comment: I think you were probably intending to change the base class specifier to use a more specific type that `ITree` in the generics, otherwise these two trees still just have children of type `ITree`, which could be either.

Comment: <ITree> is not enought, I can still put a ImportTree object into the children list of an ExportTree instance. For somereason, the compiler doesn't like it when I do `ExportTree : ParentTreeClass<ExportTree>, ITree` or `ExportTree : ParentTreeClass<ITree>`